# Отладка по USB после форматирования диска

Tags: android, java

У меня есть устройство с Android, на котором я тестирую приложение. Недавно я отформатировал свой жесткий диск и снова попытался запустить приложение по USB (для отладки). Вместо запуска увидел такую ошибку:

> Failed [`INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES`]

Приложение не запускается. При этом в `adb devices` моё устройство есть.
Как исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сообщение уведомляет о том, что новый вариант приложения (apk-файл) был собран с другой цифровой подписью, нежели уже установленная на устройство версия приложения. Надо просто удалить старую, а затем поставить новую (явно или из Ecplise)

```
adb uninstall com.example.sample
```

Ну, и если есть сомнения в правильности подписи (что маловероятно, скорее просто иначе собирали)

```
jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs
```